# How to add a second query as a condition?

Tags: php

Please see my query below. Right now its look for system_id from contacts where system_id = '$sid' but i want the query to ALSO look for friend_id from contacts where system_id = '$sid'

```
$tre = mysql_query("SELECT System_id, Full_name FROM accounts 
WHERE Full_name LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'])."%' LIMIT 5");
while($re=mysql_fetch_array($tre))
{
   $qry=mysql_query("SELECT System_id FROM contacts WHERE 
   System_id='". $sid ."' AND Friend_id='". $re['System_id'] ."'");
   if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0){
      if($sid!=$re['user_id']){
         $obx['id']=$re['System_id'];
         $obx['name']=$re['Full_name'];
         $arr[]=$obx;
      }
   }
```

How do i tweak it?

Thanks!

Update:

Upon looking up some of the comments below i structured this query that works as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contacts.friend_id, accounts.full_name, 
accounts.system_id
FROM contacts, accounts
WHERE (contacts.system_id = '$sid' AND contacts.friend_id 
= accounts.system_id) OR (contacts.friend_id = '$sid' 
AND contacts.system_id = accounts.system_id)
```

The only problem is how do i change the SELECT query from this:

```
$tre = mysql_query("SELECT System_id, Full_name FROM accounts 
WHERE Full_name LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'])."%' LIMIT 5");
```

To $tre:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contacts.friend_id, accounts.full_name, 
accounts.system_id
FROM contacts, accounts
WHERE (contacts.system_id = '$sid' AND contacts.friend_id 
= accounts.system_id) OR (contacts.friend_id = '$sid' 
AND contacts.system_id = accounts.system_id)
```

Comment: either do a join on contacts, or a subquery

Comment: Why isn't this working?  Maybe `sid` is not defined yet?

Comment: This is the classic (n+1) query problem.  You'll be dying a latent death when the number of contacts is large.

Comment: Hello all, i updated my question with a working solution.  Now i just need help putting the new query inside $tre.  Thanks all!